# Building project in Android Studio failing

Tags: android, gradle

The problem is I've been trying to build my project since this morning and can't due to this error of a dependency:

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X0TO.png)

(Note: I haven't got that dependency implemented in my build.gradle Module).

I've tried almost all I could, from putting the dependency 3.0.0 to reinstalling Android Studio, and still got the error.

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` files

Answer (score 0):

Jcenter was down that day, and that repository was the one which made me have that error.